# Can i import the bundle products in magento by using csv?

Tags: magento-1.8, php, csv

i want to import the bundle products by using csv in magento.i am import the bundle products by using dataflows its import the bundle products but its not show the bundle items in backend.

headers my csv files:

store   websites    attribute_set   type    category_ids    sku has_options vendor  color   status  tax_class_id    visibility  price   cost    weight      url_key gift_message_available  url_path options_container  description meta_keyword    short_description bundle_options bundle_selections

plz give the correct headers csv.

thanx,
Rama Krishna

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with CSV and magento is to use MAGMI. It's easy to create bundle products with it - just in one row. You can check official documentation in wiki.magmi.org, and here is couple of examples:

The simplest syntax for importing bundle products:

```
 ....,bundle_skus,....
 ....,"CPU:sku001;CPU:sku002",....
```

And the advanced one

```
 ....,store,bundle_options,bundle_skus,....
 ....,en,"-*;CPU:Central Processing Unit:radio:1:0;RAM:Random Access Memory:SKU:1:1","CPU:sku001:1:0:1:0;CPU:sku002:1:0:0:1;RAM:sku1000;RAM:sku1001;RAM:sku1002",....
```

You can find more examples of magmi syntax in the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgOC3MxA5YaLdFFwTk9uY2RQbmthQmZZdmVYZ3FUOEE&usp=drive_web#gid=0

If you consider paid extensions there is a nice extension [here](http://www.magelynx.com/import-export-plugin.html), it's an ui wrap around MAGMI that has all the features tuned out of the box and supports exports in magmi format as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'd give [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) a shot. [Here](http://brandoncole.org/2014/09/using-magmi-with-your-magento-store/) a tutorial I've written that covers part of it. The [wiki for magmi](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Bundle_Item_processor) can help you figure out how the bundled product system works exactly.

Answer (score 1):

try **import/export** module. I thing this the best solution for you.

1> download sample file

2>then fill up csv and import it

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot import bundles using import/export or data flow profiles. If you look in

app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml 
around line 94 you will find this:

```
<import_product_types>
     <simple>importexport/import_entity_product_type_simple</simple>
     <configurable>importexport/import_entity_product_type_configurable</configurable>
     <virtual>importexport/import_entity_product_type_simple</virtual>
     <grouped>importexport/import_entity_product_type_grouped</grouped>
</import_product_types>
```

You can see what product types are supported in import/export. So the only way to import is to use magmi or write a module that extends magento core to support bundles.

Adding the columns as suggested above will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the ImportExport Module, which is much faster and supports bundles. The following columns are required:

```
sku,
_type,
_attribute_set,
_product_websites,
name,
price,
description,
short_description,
weight,
status,
visibility,
tax_class_id,
qty,
is_in_stock,
rice_view,
price_type,
_bundle_option_required,
_bundle_option_position,
_bundle_option_type,
_bundle_option_title,
_bundle_product_sku,
_bundle_product_position,
_bundle_product_is_default,
_bundle_product_qty,
_bundle_product_can_change_qty
```

Comment: thanx thorsten,

Comment: i am trying in this way create a bundle product but it not show bundle items for that bundle product

Comment: did you create the bundle option as simple products? This can be done in the same file.